# LightDM add Window Manager (Openbox)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, window-managers, display-manager

I'm running my application (GUI) in kiosk mode via LightDM. This works fine, but i'm having a hard time including openbox to it. My application simply has no borders or decorations, although i'm setting openbox as `user-session`

**lightdm.conf:**

```
[SeatDefaults]
user-session=openbox
autologin-user= xxxx
autologin-user-timeout=0
session-setup-script= /home/xxxx/Desktop/runapp.sh // run application
```

in `/usr/share/xsessions` there is a `openbox.desktop` file, so i don't know why its not working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the solution is pretty easy.

You need to create a **`autostart.sh`** file located in **`/home/xxx/.config/openbox/autostart.sh`**

If you don't have an **`openbox`** folder, just create one.

this is what my **`autostart.sh`** file looks like:

```
cd /home/xxx/Desktop/app         //switch to folder where my app is located
./runapp                        // run my app
```

make it executable: **`chmod +x autostart.sh`**

**`lightdm.conf`**

```
[SeatDefaults]
user-session=openbox
autologin-user= xxx
autologin-user-timeout=0
```

Now, when I'm booting, my GUI application is shown correctly using the openbox window manager.